# What is our stance on questions on medical careers?

Tags: discussion, scope

What is our stance on questions on medical careers? Are they on-topic or off-topic?

Example: [What is the best method to get a non-student clinical rotation in the US?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/18889/43)

> Medical students in the US usually participate in several clinical rotations before they graduate. What about someone who is not a student, but does have medical license (passed the USMLE tests), and is interested in doing a clinical rotation? I have noticed that hospitals list general information about rotations, but do not list them under their "career" open jobs. Any recommendations?

Comment: Related old question: https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/262/290

Answer (score 6):

Although it's not listed as one of the specifically on-topic categories, I think the default should be to include rather than exclude. I see no harm in a well-formed question about medical careers and/or education as long as it meets the other basic requirements (prior research, not just opinion, etc).